# Spring MVC and @RequestParam with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to build an API that takes a POST with one parameter in the body that should be **x-www-form-urlencoded**. I've currently mapped it as:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = POST,  consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<LinkEntity> createShortLink(@RequestBody String url) {
    LinkEntity savedLink = linkService.create(url);
 }
```

When I do a POST with Postman (REST Chrome extension) with one form parameter **url=http://www.drissamri.be** it comes into this method as **url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.drissamri**.be as expected.

When I try to change the **@Requestbody** into  **@RequestParam(value = "url")** I still get the URL with the url= prefix (as expected) but it is not urlencoded anymore. Why doesn't the encoding take place any more? Is this a bug or is there another way to take in the parameter as urlencoded value

Comment: Don't you mean `@RequestParam("uri")`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I've edited the post.

Comment: `@RequestBody` maps the request body as is, `@RequestParam` takes the value out from [`ServletRequest#getParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). The latter are values from query string and in case of `x-www-form-urlencoded` POST also parameters from the body - both of course decoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly mentioned by [Pavel Horal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865403/pavel-horal) the parameter is retrieved by [ServletRequest#getParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) and is already decoded. If you need to access the origin parameter you can access the parameter by other means.

One way would be to inject a HttpServletRequest and use  [HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString) which does **not** decode the values.